# Yii2 проблема с организацией кода

Tags: yii2

Есть виджет формы обратной связи, который я подключаю на разных страницах и чтобы отправить данные на  почту мне приходится в контроллере, в каждом экшене где есть форма вставлять ниже следующий код

```
$contact = new ContactForm();
        $contact->contact();

        if ($contact->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $contact->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }//////////
```

Как бы все работает, письма отправляются, но получается что приходится постоянно дублировать код. Так же письмо отправляется если я вставляю данный код в виде виджета, но тогда выдает ошибку строка `return $this->refresh();`

Подскажите как быть. Только познаю Yii2=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Вариант 1***:
Создай родительский контроллер к примеру `BaseController{}`
у него в методе `init()` пропиши свой код.
Далее все контроллеры где есть форма обратной связи наследуй от `BaseController{}`

***Вариант 2***:
В каждом контроллере где есть форма обратной связи пропиши свой код в методе `init()`

***Вариант 3***:
Создай родительский контроллер к примеру `BaseController{}`
в нём создай метод `checkFeedBack()` с твоим кодом.
Далее все контроллеры наследуй от `BaseController{}`, а в `action` где надо проверять и отправлять форму вызывай метод `$this->checkFeedBack();`

Comment: спасибо. отличный вариант. сам не допер=)